# Equivalence of powershell += on vb.net when declaring variables

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, powershell, declare

I have the following code that I'm translating from powershell to vb.net

```
for ($a=1; $a -le $intPasswordLength; $a++)
    {
        if ($a -gt 3)
        {
            $b = $rand.next(0,3) + $a
            $b = $b % 3 + 1
        } else { $b = $a }
        switch ($b)
        {
            "1" {$b = "$strNumbers"}
            "2" {$b = "$strCapitalLetters"}
            "3" {$b = "$strLowerLetters"}
        }
        $charset = $($b)
        $number = $rand.next(0,$charset.Length)
        $RandomPassword += $charset[$number]
    }
    $RandomPassword
}
```

The variable `$RandomPassword` is being declared and increased at the same time if I understand correctly, by the value `$charset[$number]`

what would be the equivalent on vb.net? how could I declare this and increase it by the value `charset(number)` on vb.net?

Thanks!

Comment: if randomword is string: `RandomPassword += charset(number)` and charset can be string or Char().  For a stringbuilder: `RandomWord.Append(charset(number))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just string concatentation and `+=` works for that in VB as well:

```
Dim s As String = "foo"
s += " bar"
```